# Maven Embedder - getting a list of profiles

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-embedder

How do I get a list of all the profiles for a project in maven inside of a maven plugin?

Would it be:

```
MavenEmbedder.readModel(new File("path to pom.xml")).getProfiles();
```

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, that was easy. The answer is: yes. :-)